# Unable to read values django queryset

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to Django & python, and struggling to put pieces together. I'm not able to read the values from my db and populate in a template.

Q1)

In the local vars section, i see my variables as `<TblManufacturer: object....>` and at times
as a key value pair. Can someone tell me how to read values from that? I tried `object.get(key)` which didn't work.

models.py:

```
class Tblmanufacturer(models.Model):
  manufacturerid = models.IntegerField(db_column='manufacturerID', primary_key=True)
  manufacturername = models.CharField(db_column='manufacturerName', unique=True)
  createdon = models.DateTimeField(db_column='CreatedOn')
  class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'tblmanufacturer'
```

inspectdb created the model file for me.

```
>>> lstMan = Tblmanufacturer.objects.values('manufacturername').filter(manufacturerid=1)
>>> print lstMan
>>> [{'manufacturername': u'Nokia'}]
```

How do i read Nokia from this? and how to read the member values from queryset object? `<TblManufacturer object... >`

Q2)  Is the `__unicode__()` method a must to use? Why and to use? I read djangbook and docs, can't seem to unserstand it. :(

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1. `lstMan` works like list. Use index to get the first item (a dictinoary); then use another index to get a value from the dictionary.

```
>>> lstMan = [{'manufacturername': u'Nokia'}]
>>> lstMan[0]['manufacturername']
u'Nokia'
```

Q2. Try following code with / without `__unicode__` defined. You will get different results according to [`__unicode__1`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__unicode__) existence.

```
print unicode(Tblmanufacturer.objects.get(manufacturerid=1))
```

- Example

  ```
  >>> class KlassWith__unicode__(object):
  ...     def __unicode__(self):
  ...         return u'Klass Object!'
  ...
  >>> class KlassWithout__unicode__(object):
  ...     pass
  ...
  >>> print unicode(KlassWithout__unicode__())
  <__main__.KlassWithout__unicode__ object at 0x0000000002A37780>
  >>> print unicode(KlassWith__unicode__())
  Klass Object!
  ```

Comment: hey thanks. am able to retrieve value that way. while i tried to do the same thing by, 
    >>> lMan = Tblmanufacturer.objects.all()
    >>> lMan
[<Tblmanufacturer: 1>, <Tblmanufacturer: 2>, <Tblmanufacturer: 3>, <Tblmanufacturer: 4>, <Tblmanufacturer: 5>, <Tblmanufacturer: 6>]
    >>> lMan[0]
<Tblmanufacturer: 1>
    >>> lMan[0]['manufacturerid']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Tblmanufacturer' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

getting some error. while i was getting a column initially, i am doing select * here. not sure whats wrong

Comment: @GopinathR, You used `values()` in the question code, while didn't use it in the comment code. `values()` yields dictionaries. Without `values()`, it yields Model instance. So it should be slightly modified: `lstMan[0].manufacturername`

Comment: awesome. sounds logical. Thanks a ton :)